# Make your own Ubuntu Kernel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

I was trying to build my own kernel using Ubuntu 14.04.2 but have run into a problem. I was following this tutorial: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel but got stuck on "Modifying the configuration" part. When I type the first line in: "chmod a+x debian/scripts/*", it says debian/scripts not found.

I figured I'll just skip it and go to next part but when I type "fakeroot debian/rules clean", it says debian/rules not found. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

I want to make a kernel with less "bloat". I'm mostly doing this for the learning experience.

Comment: Don't skip anything. `find . -type d -name debian` to confirm it is or isn't there before you go skipping items.  Find out why. Your configuration is generally nothing more than cloning your current kernel config with `make cloneconfig > /dev/null 2>&1` or the like (check for current Ubuntu)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you very much! I got into the makeconfig screen. How do I exclude things? I tried deleting the asterisks but they don't want to change.

Comment: Oh it has been a long time since I built my own kernel. You should be able to toggle the options in the config screen. **Note:** leaving unused items on has little impact on the kernel size or behavior. Unless there is something specific you need to turn off due to a hardware conflict, etc. if you can't turn them off easily, there is no harm leaving them on.